# In Jupyter Notebook -- No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm working in a Windows 10 Enterprise environment. I have been using Jupiter Notebooks successfully for several months, and all of a sudden this morning I'm getting the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

So, I go to my Anaconda cmd prompt and type:  `pip install pandas`

Then, I get this.

```
(base) C:\Users\RS>pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\rs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\rs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\rs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\rs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\rs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

For some weird reason, I have to start the Jupyter Notebook like this '`python -m notebook`'. If I just enter '`jupyter notebook`' in the Anaconda command prompt, I get this.

```
(base) C:\Users\RShuell>jupyter notebook
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\python.exe C:\Users\RS\jupyter-script.py notebook'
```

Again, everything was working perfectly fine for the last several months, and I'm not sure what changed over the weekend.

Comment: Do you have more than one python release installed? could you please add the results of this command? `where python` in the CMD

Comment: Result is 3 lines of executables: 
C:\Users\RS\python.exe & 
C:\Users\RS\Anaconda3\python.exe &
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe

Comment: And when you're typing solely `python` in the CMD - what version does it use? what version is in the `C:\Users\RS\Anaconda3` path? (go into that directory and you'll see some executables and one of them contains the version in the file's name)

Comment: I would go to each `python.exe`'s that is outputted by the `where python` command (in the anaconda prompt) folder and explicitly use the executable and write: `python.exe -m pip install pandas` to ensure every version of it has `pandas` installed. As for the `jupyter notebook` not working - maybe some environment variables have been changed, check in the environment variables, in the Path section you have the `Python<Version>/Scripts` folder, with a jupyter.exe in it.

Comment: Something got switched to a new path. The 'where python' helped me figure it out. Thanks for that! I've never used that before, but it's super handy!! So, anyway, I changed my directory to the new path and loaded a saved '.ipnyb' that I had backed up just before the incident....very lucky to have done so!! Thanks again!!

Comment: (Maybe you just tried pip because things were being weird? If not...) Also as an aside for future better experience, consistently stick with using conda to install things available via a conda channel. Because you are using Anaconda, given things like `c:\users\rs\anaconda3\ `, you'll run into less problems in the long run and have more portable environments sticking with `conda` to install and not `pip`. Pandas is definitely available via Anaconda, see [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas) and so use conda as your primary package manager and only use `pip` when it's not an option.